# ‘alike’ vs ‘similar’

Tags: word-choice

> The two sisters are only **alike** in appearance. In character, they are strikingly different.

Why not use **similar** instead of **alike**？

Comment: Why not use **alike**?

Comment: Why not use **dissimilar** instead of **different**? When you have two equally valid options, it becomes a matter of preference/taste/style which one to use. That said, I think *"look alike"* is more common than *"look similar"*.

Comment: I can not tell the difference between them. @OldBrixtonian

Comment: _Alike_ and _similar_ may be synonyms according to the dictionary, but in practice people often use _similar_ to mean 'somewhat resembling one another' rather than 'exactly alike'.

Comment: @KateBunting  In similiarity, is similar > alike ?

Comment: @Y. zeng I have to agree with Kate on this. Therefore I would symbolise this as  similar < alike.

Answer (score 1):

> The two sisters are only alike in appearance. In character, they are strikingly different.

Q.

> **Why not use similar instead of alike？**

---

**I would have automatically used alike in this particular sentence**. However when I read the question I had to think why. My thoughts were two fold

1. Alike sounds the same as Like
2. Similar is close but not the same.

When I checked the dictionary I found my thoughts were nearly correct Alike implies a stronger sense of being nearly the same, but only used in a correct way. Alike and Similar are both used as adjectives in the context shown and they mean the same. In fact in my dictionary, when used as above, similar is used to describe "alike" However **when Alike is used as an adverb after a noun it means equally**. It is not along step from equally to equal and equal means, **the same** in amount, number, or size. So this word usage, even though it was technically incorrect, had influenced my thoughts with regard to which word to use.

---

The two sisters are in appearance alike. In character, they are strikingly different

---

> **alike adverb [only after n**, not gradable] (**EQUALLY**) equally; both:

> Adjectives are words that describe nouns (or pronouns). "Old," "green," and "cheerful" are examples of adjectives. (It might be useful to think of adjectives as "describing words.")

All Ref CED [**Alike**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/alike) [Similar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/similar)  [**Equal**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/equal)